# How to share static ConcurrentDictionary between two classes

Tags: c#, static, concurrentdictionary

So i want to share my concurrent dictionary object between two classes, dictionary object is static. top of my head thinking to do something like this.
but i believe there should be better way to do this. is there any way around so i don't need to pass dictionary in constructor.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Instance inst= new Instance();
        inst.AddValue();

        Service serv= new Service(Instance.staticDictnry);
        inst.AddValue2();

        serv.DoSomething();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Instance
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, String> staticDictnry= new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    private Service s1;
    public Instance()
    {
        s1 = new Service(staticDictnry);
    }
    public void AddValue()
    {
        staticDictnry.TryAdd("A", "A1");
    }
    public void AddValue2()
    {
        staticDictnry.TryAdd("B", "B1");
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dictionary;
    public Service(ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _dictionary)
    {
        dictionary = _dictionary;
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value " + keyValuePair.Key + " Key "+ keyValuePair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a class which merely wraps a static object is probably a bad idea, for one.

Comment: You don't need an instance with a static object.  Use Instance.ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: A better way to do what? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Derive the Service Class from the Instance Class so that you can use the Static Dictionary [ConcurrentDictionary] in the Service Class without passing it as a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, there is absolutely no reason to have a instance class that has no instance fields but only uses static fields. Use static methods instead, if your behavior does not depend on instances, or use a static instance of the `Instance` class.

In the `Service` class, you generally have the problem that inside this class, you have no idea what is happening with the dictionary that you reference in a instance field. Because the static variable in `Instance` is public and not `readonly`, you do not even know that this dictionary is the same anymore than the one that is referenced by the static field.

So, I would say, yes, there is for sure a better way to do this, but how this should be done depends on what you want to achieve, exactly.